# Set index on ComboBox.ItemsSource changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm using Bindings to set the ItemsSource of a combobox.
How can I set the index of my combobox to 0 without an event handler or will I have to use an event handler?

SelectedIndex in WPF gets ignored since SelectedValue is already assigned to a binding.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Class}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource classList}}"
          SelectedIndex="0"/>
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding ItemSubClass}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Class.AvailableSubClasses}" 
          SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Selected value on cb2 is null when cb1.value changes. And cb1.value is null on load.

Comment: please, show code of your binding to ComboBox

Comment: No. `SelectedIndex="0"` should be what you want. BTW show your code!

Comment: Can you show the viewmodel also

Comment: Apparently it sets selectedindex for cb2 only once and not at all for cb1

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" fixes cb2. however cb1 which loads from a static method still doesn't set selected.

Comment: SelectedValue and SelectedIndex do the same thing so they are competing.  Drop SelectedIndex="0".  If Class is null then just assign Class to the first item in classList in the get.

Comment: Guess I'll just add SelectedIndex = 0 in the constructor

Comment: Do not use SelectedIndex. Create and use a "IsSelected" property in your model to determine what item(s) the user has selected.